# Deleting Cookie / Session on the Server and on the Client Side Perl CGI

Tags: perl, session, cookies, cgi

I'm running into a problem where my logout page is not removing the cookie. Can anyone tell me what's wrong? I'm trying to remove it on the server and on the client side. Down below I provided a sample of my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
use CGI::Session;
use CGI::Carp qw (fatalsToBrowser);

my $q = new CGI;
my $sid = $q->cookie("Cool-123") || undef;
$session = new CGI::Session(undef, $sid, {Directory => '/tmp'});
$session->delete();
my $cookie = $q->cookie(Cool-123 => '');
print $q->header( -cookie=>$cookie ); 

print <<END;    

<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

<!-- Javascript/Jquery
=============================================================== -->
<script src="/~js/redirect.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure what you are having a problem with here.  It looks like this would work fine for a logout script.  Are you worried about the cookie not deleting?  After you delete the session object, the cookie would not make the session valid, so the cookie shouldn't matter.  I wrote the code that I use on my web page for the most part like this, and it works fine for a logout script.  The only major difference is that I used a database instead of a file for storing the session object(s).  It doesn't delete the cookie, but it does make that cookie no longer valid.